# Why am I encountering org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException when I save or retrieve an entity through JPA Repository?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, maven

ive got this problem. Whenever i want to use JPA Repository to save an entity o to retrieve one, ive got problems with the database connection. This is currently the exception when i want to save a new entity: `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet [ERROR: relation "id_generator" does not exist Position: 16] [n/a]`

Im also using postgresql

and this are my clases

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bpm_actions")
@SQLDelete(sql="UPDATE bpm_actions SET deleted = '1' WHERE act_id = ? and version = ?")
@Where(clause="deleted is null")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "act_id"))
public class Action extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    // Implementar la lógica de la clase aquí

    @Override
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName="bpm_actions_seq", allocationSize=1)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="id_generator", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    protected Integer   id;

    @Column(name="DELETED", nullable=true, length=1)
    protected String    deleted;



    public void extractMutableValues(Object newObject) {
        BaseEntity other = (this.getClass().cast(newObject));
        this.setVersion(other.getVersion());
    }

}
```

im using spring boot 3.0.5

Also whenever i want to retrieve a record, i get a null object, when i know for a fact that there is a record to retrieve

Comment: Your annotations are on the field not the properties (getter/setters) so your `@ SequenceGenerator ` is ignored. Ditch the property and place the annotation on your entity class instead.